# Multiple database users vs single user?

Tags: database

In a shared hosting environment where I have several websites under a single account.  As an example suppose I have 5 wordpress (or joomla, drupal, etc) sites.  Each website has a separate database and (so far) has a separate database user as well for each site.  The sites are all under my control; there is no client for which I need to worry about keeping things separate.  As I get ready to add an additional site, I'm starting to think it would be convenient to have a single shared database user that can access multiple db's rather than individual database users.

What are the pros/cons of having a separate database user for each database-backed site vs having a single database user that can access all the site's databases?  Is there a best practice?

Comment: Do you mean multiple databases inside of the same cluster with different users or basically saying person X owns x_table1, person Y owns y_table1 and y_table 2 which all all in the same database?

Comment: @Jpatrick: I'd say the former.  I'm not talking about sharing databases.  The scenario is web applications that need a database to run.  Each application has it's own database.  There is one database server which hosts all these databases. Question is should I have a single database user that can access each of these databases, or should I create a separate database user for each database.

Answer (score 2):

I would keep them separated (one user per database).

If any of your sites has a vulnerability (and people find them every day), someone might exploit it to get access to you DB engine, via the compromised user. If the user is restricted to a single database, then at least the other sites won't be compromised.

If you use a single user, then gaining access via that user puts every database (and thus, every site) in danger.

Answer (score 0):

it depends on what kind of website you have . if your website supports some kind of business intelligence then your database should be separate for a particular user to give access only to particular user for BI support will be a good idea.

if your website is simple just like some business or community site then your database can be one for all users.

ok now question come for different databases for different websites.

making one database for different website is not a good idea as accessing database using different programming language make a lot of difference on the processing speed. like Python is a good programming language but JAVA is many times faster than Python. so this should be keep in mind. one more thing resource sharing at the same time can create problem as user at one site making a change for some data and at the same time some other user from another website using that data then different transaction will change the data required and many problems like this.

so better option is that make separate database for separate websites. if users are performing some kind of work at a particular data then make separate access to that data only  for that particular user which he/she required,so you can make separate table or db in this case. other benefit of separate database is that you can perform parallel load of data using multiple process or threads . which make database access very fast.just like data of 10 GB in 10 files can be access fast by using 10 threads. A part from this you use one thread to access data of 10 GB from one file. :) 
one more benefit is that your resources will not get changed so easily by applying different transaction at the same time, as probability will get low for separate databases.
Good luck.